# Map azure cdn static content to existing domain name

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I have used cloud flare, the setup was very easy, just adding name servers helped out. But I am trying to do this in azure cdn.

I have created cdn profile and cdn end points for our web site http://example.com/ hosted in azure

**Image in Origin Sever**

```
http://example.com/Content/images/example-12169.jpg
```

**Image in CDN**

```
http://example.azureedge.net/Content/images/example-12169.jpg
```

And now I have to change my application code to fetch from azure cdn.

**Example :**

From

```
<img src="~/Content/images/example-12169.jpg" />
```

To

```
<img src="http://example.azureedge.net/Content/images/example-12169.jpg" />
```

**Update:**

I can see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain) doc , explaining `C Name` for sub domain , but how can i do it for root domain because it already has `C Name` named `www` for `example.azurewebsites.net`

**Update 2:**

For SEO purpose we need to set our domain with www.example.com , so the CNAME setup was

```
a   @   0.0.0.0 600 seconds

txt     @   example.azurewebsites.net   1 Hour

cname   www     example.azurewebsites.net   1 Hour
```

For using azure CDN with www subdomain I updated the CNAME value from `example.azurewebsites.net` to `example.azureedge.net` , so the CNAME setup is

```
cname   www     example.azureedge.net   1 Hour
```

Now when try to access www.example.com , I get Access denied.

I am using Akamai Standard CDN.

How can I Map azure cdn static content to existing domain name without changing the application code ?

Answer (score 0):

Is your html page which references the .jpg also on the CDN? If it is, you should not need to change the relative path. If not, you will need to rewrite to use the CDN explicitly.

Regarding your second question, since CNAME of an apex (or root) domain is not allowed, you can either do a http redirect from the apex domain to the www., or you can use a CDN provider that supports apex domains, such as DNSimple's ALIAS record and DNS Made Easy's ANAME record.

Comment: Thanks for responding, Our html page is hosted in Origin Server Azure Web App. Regarding CNAME issue i have updated the question explaining what i have tried. Option to Switch from Go Daddy to new DNS provider is time consuming task. I guess Only solution would be to do rewrite, `images`, `.js` and `.css` using `web.Config` to use azure CDN.